# Maui NavigationStack artefacts

Tags: c#, navigation, maui

I'm trying to understand why I get unexpected results when navigating from one page to another. Sorry for the long post but I tried to summarize as best as I could. If anyone wants to run this code it is available on [Github](https://github.com/Artyfice/MauiArtefacts).

My `AppShell` overrides both methods

```
protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigating(args);

    DebuggingOutput.Log(GetType(), $"{args.Current?.Location.OriginalString ?? "//"} -> {args.Target.Location.OriginalString} ({args.Source})");
}

protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigated(args);

    DebuggingOutput.Log(GetType(), args.Current.Location.OriginalString);
}
```

My pages all inherits from `BaseContentPage`

```
public abstract partial class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public BaseContentPage()
    {
        Appearing += OnAppearing;
        NavigatingFrom += OnNavigatingFrom;
        NavigatedTo += OnNavigatedTo;
        NavigatedFrom += OnNavigatedFrom;
        Disappearing += OnDisappearing;
    }

    ~BaseContentPage()
    {
        Appearing -= OnAppearing;
        NavigatingFrom -= OnNavigatingFrom;
        NavigatedTo -= OnNavigatedTo;
        NavigatedFrom -= OnNavigatedFrom;
        Disappearing -= OnDisappearing;
    }

    void OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs args) => DebuggingOutput.Log(GetType());
    void OnNavigatingFrom(object sender, NavigatingFromEventArgs args) => DebuggingOutput.Log(GetType());
    void OnNavigatedTo(object sender, NavigatedToEventArgs args) => DebuggingOutput.Log(GetType());
    void OnNavigatedFrom(object sender, NavigatedFromEventArgs args) => DebuggingOutput.Log(GetType());
    void OnDisappearing(object sender, EventArgs args) => DebuggingOutput.Log(GetType());
}
```

Here's what I log to the output window

```
public static class DebuggingOutput
{
    public static void Log(Type type, string additional = null, [CallerMemberName] string method = null)
    {
#if !DEBUG
        return;
#endif
        var navigationStack = Shell.Current?.Navigation.NavigationStack
            ?.Select((x, i) =>
            {
                if (x is not IContentPage page)
                {
                    return $"{i}:NULL";
                }

                var route = (string)page.GetType().GetProperty($"{typeof(IContentPage).FullName}.{nameof(IContentPage.PageRoute)}", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);

                return $"{i}:{route}";
            }) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        Debug.WriteLine($"{type.Name}.{method} | Stack: {string.Join(", ", navigationStack)}{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(additional) ? $" | Additional: {additional}" : "")}", "DEBUG");
    }
}
```

**Case 1:**

1. From *//logon* I go to *//page1*
2. From *//page1* I go to *//logon*
3. From *//logon* I go to *//page1*

```
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigating | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //login -> //page1 (ShellItemChanged)
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatingFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnDisappearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnAppearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigated | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //page1
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatedFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnNavigatedTo | Stack: 0:NULL

[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigating | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //page1 -> //login (ShellItemChanged)
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnNavigatingFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnDisappearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnAppearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigated | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //login
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnNavigatedFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatedTo | Stack: 0:NULL

[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigating | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //login -> //page1 (ShellItemChanged)
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatingFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnDisappearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnAppearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigated | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //page1
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatedFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnNavigatedTo | Stack: 0:NULL
```

**Case 2:**

1. From *//logon* I go to *//page1*
2. From *//page1* I go to *page2*
3. From *//page1/page2* I go to *//logon*
4. From *//logon* I go to *//page1*

```
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigating | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //login -> //page1 (ShellItemChanged)
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatingFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnDisappearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnAppearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigated | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //page1
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatedFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnNavigatedTo | Stack: 0:NULL

[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigating | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //page1 -> page2 (Push)
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnNavigatingFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnDisappearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page2.OnAppearing | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigated | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2 | Additional: //page1/page2
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnNavigatedFrom | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2
[0:] DEBUG: Page2.OnNavigatedTo | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2

[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigating | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2 | Additional: //page1/page2 -> //login (ShellItemChanged)
[0:] DEBUG: Page2.OnNavigatingFrom | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2
[0:] DEBUG: Page2.OnDisappearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnAppearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigated | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //login
[0:] DEBUG: Page2.OnNavigatedFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatedTo | Stack: 0:NULL

[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigating | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //login -> //page1 (ShellItemChanged)
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatingFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnDisappearing | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2 <-- WHY IS page2 on the stack?
[0:] DEBUG: Page2.OnAppearing | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2 <-- NOT EXPECTING THAT
[0:] DEBUG: Page2.OnDisappearing | Stack: 0:NULL, 1:page2 <-- NOT EXPECTING THAT
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnAppearing | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: AppShell.OnNavigated | Stack: 0:NULL | Additional: //page1/page2 <-- NOT EXPECTING THAT
[0:] DEBUG: LoginPage.OnNavigatedFrom | Stack: 0:NULL
[0:] DEBUG: Page1.OnNavigatedTo | Stack: 0:NULL
```

Why is there an artifact of *page2* in the stack?

The documentation says **//route The route hierarchy will be searched for the specified route, upwards from the current position. The matching page will replace the navigation stack.**

I would have expected to never see page2 in the stack after I went from *//page1/page2* to *//login* since I'm then going from *//login* to *//page1*.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I would like to reproduce the issue but the link you provided cannot be reached. Could you send the project link again?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Sorry the repo was private. Switched it to public.

Comment: I tested the repo and found the same situation. This is the issue with the relative routes, no matter the format: //route or ///route. I find it will awaken the latest page, then turn to the target page. But if I change it to register route, the error will not appear.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Thanks for confirming my issue. What do you mean "if I change it to register route"?

Comment: I tested this method `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("targetpage");`  and it will not cause this issue.